# How to handle concurrent file write requests on a node server with socket.io

Tags: node.js, file, socket.io

How to handle concurrent file write requests on a node server with socket.io. I am using this to write:

```
fs.writefile('abc.txt','datatobewritten','utf8',function(err){});
```

I have a file abc.txt and suppose two users try to write on the same time on this file then I am getting an error, so how do I queue multiple requests.

Comment: try to write as sync methods

Answer (score 12):

You have to synchronize the writes.

For a single instance of nodejs you can use simple queue, like this:

```
module.exports = function(path, content, cb){
    var queue = queues[path];
    if (queue == null)
        queue = queues[path] = new Queue;

    queue.add(path, content, (err) => {
        cb(err);
        queue.next();
    });         
};

var fs = require('fs');
var queues = {};

class Queue {
    constructor () {
        this.queue = [];
    }
    next () {
        if (this.queue.length === 0)
            return;

        var [path, content, cb] = this.queue[0];
        fs.writeFile(path, content, 'utf8', (err) => {
            this.queue.shift(); 
            cb(err);
        }); 
    }       
    add (...args) {
        this.queue.push(args);
        if (this.queue.length === 1) {
            this.next();
        }
    }
}
```

In **multi-process** instance you have to use some locking, for example with [lockfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lockfile).

```
var lockFile = require('lockfile');
var fs = require('fs');


module.exports = function(path, content, cb) {
    lockFile.lock('foo.lock', function (err) {
        if (err) return cb(err);

        fs.writeFile(path, content, cb);
        lockFile.unlock('foo.lock');
    });
}
```

*For better performance you can even combine 2 approaches here.*

Comment: I have multiple processes writing to the file, how would I combine these two approaches?

Comment: Why not use WriteStream https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

Comment: Wouldn't this get stuck if there are a million concurrent writes? The callback will be called only once `fs.writeFile` is finished, so let's say there are a million requests to write something on the same file, then the last write in the queue could take a lot of time to finish.

Comment: in your example `path === 'foo.lock'`?

Answer (score 2):

You should write a module names `logs` or what ever you like.

> logs.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./abc.txt');

module.exports = {
  /* PUSH */
  write: function (message, cb) {
      writeStream.write(message, cb);
  }
}
```

Then in your socket.io related module just require the module at the top like

`var logs = require('./logs');`

and write message like this in the socket.io callbacks ! :)

`logs.write('datatobewritten');`

> Bottom line
>   "use `fs.createWriteStream` instead of `fs.writefile`"

Hope this makes sense :)