# node.js data consistency when iterating asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, concurrency, couchdb

I have a tool who's basic idea is as follows:

```
//get a bunch of couchdb databases. this is an array
    const jsonFile = require('jsonfile');
    let dbList = getDbList();
    const filePath = 'some/path/to/file';
    const changesObject = {};


     //iterate the db list. do asynchronous stuff on each iteration
     dbList.forEach(function(db){
        let merchantDb = nano.use(db);

        //get some changes from the database. validate inside callback 
        merchantDb.get("_changes", function(err,changes){
          validateChanges(changes);
          changesObject['db'] = changes.someAttribute;
          //write changes to file
          jsonFile.writeFile(filePath, changesObject, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              logger.error("Unable to write to file: ");
            }
          });
    })

const validateChanges = function(changes) {
 if (!validateLogic(changes) sendAlertMail();
}
```

For performance improvements the iteration is not done synchronously. Therefore there can be multiple iterations running in 'parallel'. My question is can this cause any data inconsistencies and/or any issues with the file writing process?

**Edit:**
The same file gets written to on each iteration.

**Edit:2**
The changes are stored as a JSON object with key value pairs. The key being the db name.

Comment: There's too much guesswork required to answer this question (I realize after having embarked on an answer). What's `jsonFile`? What's `file`? Do you really mean `nano.use('db')` rather than `nano.use(db)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really writing to a **single** file, which you appear to be (though it's hard to be sure), then no; you have a race condition in which multiple callbacks will try to write to the same file, possibly at the same time (remember, I/O isn't done on the JavaScript thread in Node unless you use the `*Sync` functions), which will at best mean the last one wins and will at worst mean I/O errors because of overlap.

If you're writing to separate files for each `db`, then provided there's no cross-talk (shared state) amongst `validateChanges`, `validateLogic`, `sendAlertMail`, etc., that should be fine.

Just for detail: It will start tasks (jobs) getting the changes and then writing them out; the callbacks of the calls to `get` won't be run until later, when all of those jobs are queued.

You are creating closures in loops, but the way you're doing it is okay, both because you're doing it within the `forEach` callback and because you're not using `db` in the `get` callback (which would be fine with the `forEach` callback but not with some other ways you might loop arrays). Details on that aspect in [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) if you're interested.

This line is suspect, though:

```
let merchantDb = nano.use('db');
```

I suspect you meant (no quotes):

```
let merchantDb = nano.use(db);
```

---

For what it's worth, it sounds from the updates to the question and your various comments like the better solution would be **not** to write out the file separately each time. Instead, you want to gather up the changes and then write them out.

You can do that with the classic Node-callback APIs you're using like this:

```
let completed = 0;
//iterate the db list. do asynchronous stuff on each iteration
dbList.forEach(function(db) {
    let merchantDb = nano.use(db);

    //get some changes from the database. validate inside callback 
    merchantDb.get("_changes", function(err, changes) {
        if (err) {
            // Deal with the fact there was an error (don't return)
        } else {
            validateChanges(changes);
            changesObject[db] = changes.someAttribute; // <=== NOTE: This line had 'db' rather than db, I assume that was meant to be just db
        }
        if (++completed === dbList.length) {
            // All done, write changes to file
            jsonFile.writeFile(filePath, changesObject, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error("Unable to write to file: ");
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes it should be `nano.use(db)`. I have added some import statements for better readability. And it is the same file that gets written to on each iteration.

Comment: @fsociety: Then no, it's not at all safe. You're scheduling multple I/O operations on a single file, which could overlap (remember, I/O isn't done on the JavaScript thread in Node unless you use the `*Sync` functions), and even if they didn't overlap, it would be "last one wins" as you haven't specified an append option. From `writeFile` (which `jsonfile.writeFile` wraps): *"Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists."*

Comment: There is an append implemented at each iteration. I have modified the question to reflect this. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle the file writes here? A simple queuing implementation like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010450/how-to-handle-concurrent-file-write-requests-on-a-node-server-with-socket-io) maybe?

Comment: @fsociety: Given you're doing a bunch of updates, do you really want to write multiple times rather than just once when you're done?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but the only way of doing that would be to make the iterations synchronous right? Because to know "when i'm done" would mean a callback function. That's too much of a performance hit because this process is scheduled to run every 30 secs, therefore should complete within 30 secs.

Comment: @fsociety: No, knowing when you're done with multiple asynchronous operations does not require making them synchronous. Yes, it would involve a callback function. I don't see why that would be a problem, as the current code uses a callback function. Three, in fact. :-) If you have time constraints, I'd **definitely** avoid unnecessary I/O. I've updated the answer to show how you could do it in this case.

Comment: wouldn't that implementation cause any issues with multiple callbacks updating the `completed` variable? Or does the single threaded nature of JS guarantee such scenarios would never occur?

Comment: @fsociety: JavaScript, the language, isn't necessarily single-threaded. But Node runs only a single JavaScript thread, so we don't have to worry about concurrency in the above, no.